# PHP Build and order an array of objects stored as JSON on a database

Tags: php, arrays, json, database

I have objects stored in json_encoded format in a database, in a text field.

I want to build an array of these objects, and then order them based on a property called "order".

The objects properties are defined on the class:

```
class Task {

public $id;
public $title;
public $details;
public $order;
public $high_priority;
public $done;

}
```

The objects are stored in a table with the following columns:

**id, title ,data**

So, the whole objects represented by the class Task gets encoded and saved in the **data** field, with the title **task**

I need to load all the objects with the title **task** from the database, map the **id** field to the task's **id** property, then put them all in an array of objects, then order them according to the property **order** of the objects

What would be the best way to do that? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the problem to json_encode($object); save then get from database, and at last json_decode? you will get the same object from json_decode.

Comment: That's what i'm doing now.. what I'm not sure how to do is getting all the tasks objects from the database, then building the array and ordering them according to the order attribute

Comment: fetch data from database with ORDER BY, create an array, then insert objects to array like $data[] = json_decode($row['TEXT_FIELD']), and you will get $data with sorted objects

Comment: that's the problem, the order itself is in the json object, not in the database field.. the field is just plain text, which would be decoded to an object containing the order property

Comment: then save an order to database, create a field named order, fill it when you save json encoded data.

Comment: i wish I could, but the database can only have the data field. I need somehow to create the array, then order it using the attribute :(

Comment: add order to data field, $to_be_inserted_in_db = ORDER_ID.json_encode($data), then use ORDER BY data, remove ORDER_ID with str_replace before json_decode($data). But this is NOT THE BEST option...

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is a noSQL db type, The best way would be to not store the data in JSON format.

Look at all this manipulation you want to do , it would so much easier to make sense of that data if you stored each value in its own field.

Comment: my problem is I am storing different types of data on a single table, and I need the flexibility to do that without having to create a table for every new type of data I need in the future.. so I thought storing in Json would enable me to do that

Comment: it sounds like a great idea at first but it is not recommended

Comment: I see it's not the usual pattern, but I don't see why it would not be recommended, since I'll only need to retrieve data using the id field.. other operations like order or filter I could do on the array itself, right?

Comment: right it is all doable,but  in your question you mention you want to know the best way